# SubDocument updates in mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have collection structure like this.

```
application_data: {
  name : A,
  site : B,
  location : [
    { key1 : value1, key2 : value2},
    { key3 : value3, key4 : value4}
  ]
}
```

Now I want to add a another array to "location" as a sub document so that my location becomes

```
location : [
  { key1 : value1, key2 : value2},
  { key3 : value3, key4 : value4, key5 :[{subkey1:subvalue1, subkey2:subvalue2}]}
]
```

I tried `$push` & `$addToSet` which did not help me. Can somebody help me?
Helpful if you explain an example using nodejs.

Comment: Can you please supply your attempts to use those operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'r actually trying to do is to add new field to an existing subdocument. You can do it using [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [positional operator $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
db.applications.update({
  name: 'A', // querying for parent document
  'location.key3': 'value3' // querying for an exact subdocument to add new field to
}, {
  $set: {
    'location.$.key5': [{
      subkey1: 'subvalue1',
      subkey2: 'subvalue2'
    }]
  }
})
```

You can achieve the same result using [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/), which is better if you want to add more than one subsubdocument to `'location.key5'`:

```
db.applications.update({
  name: 'A',
  'location.key3': 'value3'
}, {
  $push: {
    'location.$.key5': {
      subkey1: 'subvalue1',
      subkey2: 'subvalue2'
    }
  }
})
```

or

```
db.applications.update({
  name: 'A',
  'location.key3': 'value3'
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    'location.$.key5': {
      subkey1: 'subvalue1',
      subkey2: 'subvalue2'
    }
  }
})
```

See [Update Documents in an Array](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) for more info.